# TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/ registration/login.html

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

While I am creating login and logout using built-in login() and logout() views the following error occured.

**Project Name:** django_project

**App Name:** djangobin

The templates login.html, logout.html are present in 'djangobin/templates/djangobin/login.html', 'djangobin/templates/djangobin/logout.html'

TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/

registration/login.html

**Exception Type:** TemplateDoesNotExist

**Exception Value:** registration/login.html

**Reference website:** Overiq.com

**Reference website Link:** https://overiq.com/django-1-11/django-logging-users-in-and-out/#using-built-in-login-and-logout-views

**Python version:** 3.8.2

**Django version:** 3.0.5

**OS:** Windows 8.1 (32-bit)

**In settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'djangobin',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'
```

**In urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'djangobin/login.html'}, name='login'),

url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'djangobin/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
```

**In login.html:**

```
{% extends "djangobin/base.html"  %}

{% block title %}
    Login - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">

            <h4>Login</h4>
            <hr>

            {% if messages %}
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <p class="alert alert-info">{{ message }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            <form method="post">

                {% csrf_token %}

                <table class="table">
                    {{ form.as_table }}
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <h4>Related Links</h4>
            <p>
                <a href="/password-reset/">Forgot Password?</a> <br>
                <a href="/register/">Create new account.</a> <br>
                <a href="#">Feedback</a>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't add the djangobin.config in the settings.py. Try adding

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'copycat.apps.CopycatConfig',
    ...]
```

in the settings.py

EDIT:

sorry I didn't see you had added it at the end of the array. 
Did you set the login properties in the settings file?

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```